# How to easily extract the first/last element from a PSCustomObject (preferably without foreach)?

Tags: powershell

I have this JSON:

```
'{
    "fibo": {
        "2": { "hi": "there" },
        "8": { "and": "you?" }
        "5": { "well": "doing fine" },        
        "3": { "what": "is hap?" },
    }
}'
```

And I want for instance to extract the last element (the `{ "what": "is hap?" }` object), in the simplest manner possible (preferably one-liner with piping, without `foreach`-ing it).

I tried:

```
'{
    "fibo": {
        "2": { "hi": "there" },
        "8": { "and": "you?" }
        "5": { "well": "doing fine" },        
        "3": { "what": "is hap?" },
    }
}' | ConvertFrom-Json | select { $_.fibo } | select -Last 1
```

But the `select -Last 1` seems to be doing nothing.

I can use `select { $_.fibo. }` which works, but tomorrow that object may change to e.g.:

```
'{
    "fibo": {
        "2": { "hi": "there" },
        "8": { "and": "you?" }
        "5": { "well": "doing fine" },        
        "314": { "what": "is hap?" },
    }
}'
```

so I cannot rely on that..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`select -last 1` gives you last "fibo" object. But you already have only one object, but with 4 properties.

To get properties, you could use

```
    $pso = '{
        "fibo": {
            "2": { "hi": "there" },
            "8": { "and": "you?" },
            "5": { "well": "doing fine" },        
            "3": { "what": "is hap?" }
        }
    }' | ConvertFrom-Json 

# gets properties, but does not preserver order: 
$pso.fibo | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty

# this will preserve the order
$pso.fibo.psobject.properties

# so to get last property (it already has the name and value)
$prop = $pso.fibo.psobject.properties | select -Last 1
$prop
```

Comment: Almost there  `$_.fibo.psobject.properties | select -Last 1` gives `System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject 8=@{and=you?}` and even `$_.fibo.psobject.properties | select -Last 1 | select -exp value` returns something that is actually `PSCustomObject`.. but how do I get to the actual string value (of e.g. the `"you"` value associated with the `"and"` key, or even the whole `@{and=you}`, but as a simple string, not `PSCustomObject`)? everything I tried yields that `PSCustomObject` type which I cannot escape out-of, to a simple `string` that I can e.g. pipe to `clip` and use as a value?

Comment: @Tar
Yes, everything's an object :). Even property value, so you just repeat the extraction step and do what you want with it: 
`$prop.value.psobject.properties | select name,value`
And after you have selected your property, you could dynamically get it from source object by name: 
`$pso.fibo."$($prop.name)"`

Comment: Sure, everything's an object and all that... but I just don't understand how come `('{
    "fibo": {
        "2": { "hi": "there" },
        "3": { "what": "is hap?" }
    }
}' | ConvertFrom-Json).fibo.psobject.properties | select -Last 1 | select -exp value | select -exp what` works and returns an actual string/value I can e.g. pipe on to `clip` as-is, while `'{
    "fibo": {
        "2": { "hi": "there" },
        "3": { "what": "is hap?" }
    }
}' | ConvertFrom-Json | select { $_.fibo.psobject.properties | select -Last 1 | select -exp value | select -exp what }` isn't working

Comment: Just to elaborate on previous comment - the 2nd snippet "isn't working" in the sense that I am unable to extract the actual `is hap?` value out of it as-is and e.g. pipe it on to `clip`. As a simple question, how can I extract the actual value (the `"is hap?"` string) out of the second snippet (meaning, without surrounding it with parenthesis)?

Comment: @Tar To extract property value of a last outer property: `($pso.fibo.psobject.properties | select -Last 1 -ExpandProperty value).psobject.properties.Value`. Its' assuming inner properties have only one property themselves; if there's more you'd get an array.